# How to resolve this "ambiguous redirect"

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

I have a script with a function in it:

```
function install_log() {
    echo "$1" >> $INSTALL_LOG_OUTPUT 2>&1
}
```

This function is working as it should. It is a function to write something into a log file.

I added some other commands to the script, for reading the given parameters of the script:

```
AUTOMATIC_INSTALL=

for argument in "$@"
do
    install_log "-> parameter $argument"
    if [ "$argument" == "--automatic" ] || ["$argument" == "-automatic" ]; then
        AUTOMATIC_INSTALL=True
    fi
done
install_log "# AUTOMATIC_INSTALL: $AUTOMATIC_INSTALL"
```

But with the new lines, I get some non needed messages:

```
$INSTALL_LOG_OUTPUT: ambiguous redirect
```

I found out, that this comes from the two lines

```
install_log "-> parameter $argument"
# ...
install_log "# AUTOMATIC_INSTALL: $AUTOMATIC_INSTALL"
```

Does anyone know, why the messages are occurring.

Comment: `INSTALL_LOG_OUTPUT` being empty is one reason.

Comment: There is a syntax error in the second `test` of the `if` statement.  It should be `[ "$argument" == "-automatic" ]; then`.  It may or may not be related to the reported error.

Comment: @muru: You were right. The assignment of the filename for `$INSTALL_LOG_OUTPUT` was three lines later -.-

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put quotes around INSTALL_LOG_OUTPUT in your function, like this:

```
function install_log() {
    echo "$1" >> "$INSTALL_LOG_OUTPUT" 2>&1
}
```

After running your script again, you will probably get an error message indicating that INSTALL_LOG_OUTPUT is empty, with a message of this sort: `bash: : No such file or directory`.